# PerfMon Metrics Collector - Error in JMeter

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Need to know the reason for the below mentioned error, while runnig the recorded script in JMeter to calculate the hosted server's CPU, RAM utilization & performance result. Before running the test script I started the [Server Agent](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/) in my hosted server to calculate the CPU & RAM utilization of hosted server's machine.

When I connect my local machine using **LAN connection** and start running the JMeter script, I can get my CPU & RAM utilization status as mentioned in below image-1.

[image: image-1]

And when I connect my local machine using **WIFI connection** and start running the JMeter script, I cannot track my CPU & RAM utilization status and **java.net.ConnectException:Connection timed out: connect** error message displays as mentioned in below image-2.

[image]

Please let me know the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your WiFi Connection resides in the different [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) therefore JMeter cannot establish connection with the server agent.

Check subnet masks on JMeter and ServerAgent hosts, if it is not the same - most likely you won't be able to connect without specific IP [routing](https://www.metaswitch.com/resources/what-is-ip-routing) settings. You can talk to your network administrator to resolve it.

If you won't be able to connect to port 4444 of the host where the ServerAgent is running using [telnet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491013.aspx) command (or equivalent) - JMeter's Perfmon Metrics Collector listener will not be able to fetch the data as well.

---

According to [What’s the Max Number of Users You Can Test on JMeter?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter) article you should not be running the load test over WiFi so I would strongly recommend reconsidering your approach and switching back to LAN for tests execution. If you need to see how your application behaves when it is being accessed over WiFi - you can simulate slower connections by [controlling JMeter's bandwidth](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/Controlling%20Bandwidth%20in%20JMeter%20to%20simulate%20different%20networks)